# Two string version replace using sed/awk or any shell command

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Bellow is the line, i have saved in test.txt file

```
fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_v1.0.0_2017.03.22.dmp log=foo_v1.0.0_2017.03.22.log
```

i need to replace the `1.0.0` from file and log both,As you see the name "foo" is same and the version will get changed everytime.

Desired Output:

```
fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_version.2017.03.22.dmp log=foo_version.2017.03.22.log
```

Comment: it is not clear what your problem is... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: can you please save above line in test.txt file and try to run the sed commands.     if you run the                                                                                    sed -i 's/foo_.*.log/foo_version.log/g' test.txt                                                                           it will change the version of                                                                                           file=foo_v1.0.0.dmp. and i want to change thisl                              log=foo_v1.0.0.log

Comment: add your expected output for clarity.. you really need to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask... from your sed commands, I think the problem is use of `.*` which will try to match as much as possible...

Comment: from your sample, a simple `sed 's/v1\.0\.0/version/g'` should do the trick.. you need to give better example if that doesn't work...

Comment: Try this - 

`sed 's/1.0.0/version/g' f`

Comment: sundeep/vipin--- 1.0.0 will change everytime. so i cannot take as replacement string.

Comment: the edited question is completely different from the earlier one...

Comment: sundeep- could you please check now..   i have given as my desired output...   and the version will change every time..so we can't take as replcement string. if we can achive this by any other way ..like awk or cut and grep... please suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this it seems that is ok. Make sure to provide `-r` or `-E` command line switch to sed to enable extended regex support.

```
$ a="fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_v1.0.0_2017.03.22.dmp log=foo_v1.0.0_2017.03.22.log"
$ sed -r 's/(_v[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*_)/_version\./g' <<<"$a"
#Output
fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_version.2017.03.22.dmp log=foo_version.2017.03.22.log    

$ b="fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_v122.10.100_2019.11.99.dmp log=foo_v133.530.30001_201.3.0.log"
$ sed -r 's/(_v[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*_)/_version\./g' <<<"$b"
#Output
fromuser=abcd touser=efgh file=foo_version.2019.11.99.dmp log=foo_version.201.3.0.log
```

If for some reason , your sed version does not work as demonstrated above you could use also perl.
Just replace `sed -r` with `perl -pe` keeping the rest code the same and will work in all systems equipped with perl on the same way providing the required result.